# Erro ao injetar mais de uma dependência em angular.module

Tags: angularjs

Tenho o seguinte módulo:

```
var appEcommerce = angular.module("appEcommerce", [ 'ngRoute']);
```

Porém recebo um erro ao colocar outra dependência. Ex:

```
var appEcommerce = angular.module("appEcommerce", [ 'ui.mask','ngRoute']);
```

O modo como estou injetando está correto?

Esse é o erro:

> [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=appEcommerce&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.7%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.mask%26p1

Comment: você instalou o pacote `ui-mask`? usando o bower ou npm?

Comment: Acabei de descobrir o problema, eu tinha uma view que fazia parte do meu modulo appEcommerce que não estava importando a biblioteca ui.mask. Importei a mesma e o o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido.

Uma das minhas views que utilizava o meu módulo appEcommerce não importava a biblioteca ui.mask. Importei a mesma e o problema foi solucionado.